# How Can I Convert SQL Server 2012 Version 11.0.3000.0 to SQL Server 2012 Version 11.1.3000.0?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, upgrade, service-pack

I have `SQL Server 2012` with version 11.0.3000.0 .

I need upgrade my version to `SQL Server 2012 SP1` because I need install Cumulation 4 in `Sql Server 2012 Cumulative Update 4` for use `PowerPivot` in `Multidimensional Database`.

Before install `Sql Server 2012 Cumulative Update 4` I need Upgrade my `SQL Server` to `Service Pack 1`.

How Can I Update My Version to SP1.

I sow [this Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35575) and download `SQLServer2012SP1-KB2674319-x64-ENU.exe` and `SQLServer2012SP1-FullSlipstream-ENU-x64.iso` but this not work in my Server.

I have this error :